# How to include permission in Strapi plugins?

Tags: javascript, strapi

I have a plugin generated by the Strapi CLI, a standard plugin, but I intend to control the plugin's permissions through the Strapi administrator. How can I do this?

I've already tried using the array in the plugin's index file and it still didn't work.

homepagecustom is my plugin

Could anyone help? Thanks.

```
permissions: [
        // Uncomment to set the permissions of the plugin here
        {
           action: 'plugin::homepagecustom.actionType', // the action name should be plugin::plugin-name.actionType
           subject: 'nnome',
         },
      ],
```

[image]